# shell script find with pattern in file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get file name and lines from pattern matching.

The search files list are in `a.txt`.

The search patterns are in `b.txt`.

How to get file name and matching line numbers from `search files list` which contains

the patterns with shell script?

Here is the detail.

```
a.php

    ....(blah)....

b.php

    ..... phpinfo .... index ... (blah)...
```

the file list:

```
a.txt

    [file path]/a.php
    [file path]/b.php
```

the pattern list

```
b.txt

    index
    phpinfo
```

Comment: What exactly is first `detail` section?

Answer (score 1):

with pure shell

```
while read -r file 
do
  while read -r pattern
  do 
      echo "search pattern $pattern in file $file..."
      grep "$pattern" "$file"
  done < b.txt
done < a.txt
```